# How can I draw multiple lines with an offset in ComposedChart?

Tags: reactjs, line, recharts

I would like to achieve the following kind of graph with Recharts

[image: Multiple Bars and Lines]

I have been able to draw a ComposedChart with this. However, I am not able to figure out how to offset each line so that it starts with its corresponding bar.

```xml
<ComposedChart width={730} height={250} data={data}>
      <XAxis dataKey="name" />
      <YAxis />
      <Tooltip />
      <Legend />
      <CartesianGrid stroke="#f5f5f5" />
      <Bar dataKey="pv" barSize={20} fill="#413ea0" name="bar" />
      <Line
        type="linear"
        dataKey="fpv"
        stroke="#ff7300"
        name="bar"
        strokeDasharray="3 3"
      />
      <Bar dataKey="uv" barSize={20} fill="#AB3faa" />
      <Line
        type="linear"
        dataKey="fuv"
        stroke="#ffa000"
        strokeDasharray="3 3"
      />
    </ComposedChart>
```

This draws all the lines with a point at the XAxis. I cannot seem to find a way to offset the point of each line in relation to the bar.

[image: Current output]

Can someone suggest how I can achieve the effect ?
Codesandbox link is here https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-villani-mbd0p?file=/src/App.tsx

Answer (score 0):

Since I would like others to know how I achieved this - My answer is below:

I basically used 3 xAxis with different paddings.

```
<ComposedChart width={730} height={250} data={data}>
      <XAxis
        xAxisId="One"
        dataKey="name"
        padding={{ left: 0 }}
        minTickGap={10}
        allowDataOverflow={true}
        hide={true}
      />
      <XAxis
        xAxisId="Three"
        dataKey="name"
        allowDataOverflow={true}
        padding={{ left: 15, right: -15 }}
      />
      <XAxis
        xAxisId="Two"
        dataKey="name"
        padding={{ left: 30, right: -30 }}
        allowDataOverflow={true}
        hide={true}
      />

      <YAxis />
      <Tooltip />
      <Legend />
      <CartesianGrid stroke="#f5f5f5" />
      <Bar dataKey="pv" xAxisId="One" barSize={20} fill="#413ea0" name="bar" />
      <Line
        connectNulls={true}
        type="linear"
        xAxisId="One"
        dataKey="fpv"
        stroke="#ff7300"
        name="bar"
        strokeDasharray="3 3"
      />
      <Bar dataKey="uv" xAxisId="Two" barSize={20} fill="#AB3faa" />
      <Line
        xAxisId="Two"
        type="linear"
        dataKey="fuv"
        stroke="#ffa000"
        strokeDasharray="3 3"
      />
    </ComposedChart>
```

Codesandbox link is here: https://codesandbox.io/s/dank-bird-4lxeb?file=/src/App.tsx:912-2040